# How to create/load/get address of/send transaction from/create accounts under my ETH wallet? (Clarification on wallets and accounts in the ETH node)

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3.py, accounts, python

I'm totally new to the concept, but "**how can I create/load/get address of/send transaction from/create accounts under my ETH wallet**" in Ethereum node?

I'm implementing Ethereum node on my own server and connected it to my website (with Python 3, FastAPI). I am using Geth/web3.py/RPC over http, doing that. I know that one can create new addresses (0x-prefixed) using `personal_newAccount(password)`/`personal.newAccount(password)` command (I'm aware of the security risks of these commands). **Are these produced addresses, individual wallets? or just my main wallet's accounts? If they are not individual wallets' addresses, what is `personal.listwallets` command for? What is the difference between this command and `eth.accounts`? What are [web3.js's wallet-related commands](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=wallet#wallet) (which I did not find them, in web3.py and the Geth's console)** i.e., in BTC, DOGE, etc., we have our wallets and we can create accounts under our wallets (there, one can load the wallet, get balance of the wallet and the transactions are made **from wallet's address** to the receiver's address or the deposited funds are going into the wallet's balance). But so far, I just created `personal_newAccount(password)` for users and made transactions with `eth_sendTransaction` from one address to another. **Is it possible to send funds from my main wallet (not from an account) to an address?** If yes, how can I have my wallet's address to put it to the 'from' attribute of my `sendTransaction`?

I really appreciate any clarification on the wallets/accounts subject in the ETH network.

P.S., I totally have no idea about **smart-contracts** on the ETH network and how they are related to my question. If anyone wants to point out to this subject regarding replying my question, I really appreciate it if introduces a step-by-step implementation and 101 introduction to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for those who might want to be clarified on the wallet/account concepts on Ethereum, thanks to [@mikko-ohtamaa](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/620/mikko-ohtamaa).

Wallets have nothing to do with the structure being used in blockchains to track down the balances or handle transactions. It is just a file containing accounts' info(public/private keys) and `web3.eth.accounts.wallet`-based commands mentioned [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=wallet#wallet) are just to handle that.

Furthermore, Ethereum does not use the [UTXO model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspent_transaction_output), like the one in Bitcoin. [This](https://arunrajeevan.medium.com/utxo-model-in-bitcoin-vs-account-balance-model-ethereum-c5b47865e9e1) is a start point article about that. It uses an account-based model.

So, having a Bitcoin-like structure to handle transaction flow for centralized exchange structures is impossible to me. Instead, some may use the smart contracts to manage that. You can explore [this approach](https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-simple-erc20-exchange-wallet-c6720e6c8005) for a beginning step towards that. If you are going go further, see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118701/how-to-create-bitcoin-like-wallet-structure-for-ethereum) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118795/how-the-centralized-exchanges-handle-deposits).

I am looking forward any innovative ideas/comments on the subject.