# How to create Bitcoin-like wallet structure for Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, web3.py, accounts, python

'Hi everyone!

Any suggestions for an architecture to reach to Bitcoin's wallet structure for Ethereum?

Appreciate any help,
R.

- Geth version: 1.10.12-stable
- Geth's web3 api version: 0.20.1
- OS: Windows
- web3.py version: 5.25.0
- python version: 3.10.1
- I started my geth using the following command: `geth console --goerli --syncmode "light" --http --http.port 20000 --http.api personal,eth,net,web3 --allow-insecure-unlock`
- Related questions: [#1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118686/how-to-create-a-wallet) and [#2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/118693/what-is-web3s-wallet-definition-and-usage)

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions for an architecture to reach to Bitcoin's wallet structure for Ethereum?

My suggestion is don't. Ethereum is not a [UTXO blockhain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspent_transaction_output), but an account-based one. Any Bitcoin like wallet structure on Ethereum is not practical, or not needed.

For [creating a hot wallet please see this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84401/how-to-build-an-ethereum-hot-wallet-for-an-exchange/84407#84407).

Comment: Thanks again for your useful reply. Are you referring to [this approach](https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-simple-erc20-exchange-wallet-c6720e6c8005)? If yes, I did implement a modified version of this structure, but the problem was the high fee for users' contract deployment (~300k gas, ~$100 for each user's contract address). And, although I managed transferring ETH funds to the owner account without paying fee, but still had to pay fee for transferring erc20s to the owner's account. how can I minimize contract address creation & erc20 deposit fees (to send to the owner or automize it)?

Comment: If the fees are problem then just don't use Ethereum. Use some of alternative EVM compatible chains like Avalanche, Polygon. There is little you can do for the fee problem.

Comment: Thank you again for your great and innovative suggestions. As I do not have any idea on your suggestions, you mean that I can deploy my contract addresses on those chains and still be able to receive ETH and other ERC20s, with lower fees for deployment and deposits/withdrawals? I should go for it and test that. Aware of a start point? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. However, each blockchain has its own set of available tokens. There is some chain interoperability. For example, you can get the most popular tokens bridged to Polygon - transferred over Polygon bridge. So you are not getting the same set of tokens you would get on Ethereum mainnet. You are getting a different set of tokens.

Comment: I am on coinmarketcap's top-100s (which contains 44 erc20s). I hope that I be able to do the job for those 44s.. I will report the results here. Thanks again in advance